# ListView inside ScrollView, onScroll not getting called

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView inside a ScrollView.

To enable the scrolling in both ListView and ScrollView I implemented this method which I got from some other question on StackOverFlow.:-

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

The problem is that because the ListViewHeight is already to its fullest the OnScroll Method on the ListView doesnt get called. I want to execute some code when the user scrolls ( some Asynchronous loading of images ). Is there any workaround ?

My xml file for layout :-

```
<ScrollView
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="info"
            android:id="@+id/njnjj"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/gjghjgh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I understand that it is **not at all** a good practice to have a ListView inside ScrollView, but I need a workaround.

Comment: *"You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling"* from [The Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: @codeMagic I know that but at this stage, it is important for me to implement that.

Comment: Moreover, **why** do you have a **useless** LinearLayout inside another one? Also this is a **worst practice**.

Comment: @DerGolem I have other views too inside the first LinearLayout which I have not posted.

Comment: But a single RelativeLayout would replace both the LinearLayouts more efficiently.

Comment: @DerGolem I am still learning. Definitely I will improve my code as per your advice. For now, could you please state a workaround for the situation I am in ?

Comment: Sorry, but I do **fully agree** with @codeMagic. My best advice would sound like: `Re-engineer your layout, getting rid of the ScrollView`